# Python-Instagram user_recent_media returning next of none

Tags: python, instagram-api

I'm retrieving posts from Instagram with Python and populating a MySQL database. The user is myself so I have excluded the userid= parameter although I have also tried it with this in place.

Below is a snippet of my code, when I print next_ at the end, it returns 'None' and so the second while loop doesn't start. The first iteration works fine and populates the database no problem.

The code should process through all posts, in the populate function I have an if statement to take care of posts that I already have in the database and intend to make this more sophisticated by stopping the code once I reach this point. But for now this should work.

Any ideas?

```
while True:
    try:
        media_feed, next_ = api.user_recent_media()
        populate(media_feed)
        print("Processing")
        break
    except InstagramAPIError as e:
        if (e.status_code == "429"):
            print(e)
            print("Waiting")
            Wait(3600)
        else:
            print(e)
            break
print(next_)
while next_:
    while True:
        try:
            media_feed, next_ = api.user_recent_media(with_next_url=next_)
            populate(media_feed)
            print("Processing")
            break
        except InstagramAPIError as e:
            if (e.status_code == "429"):
                print(e)
                print("Waiting")
                Wait(3600)
            else:
                print(e)
                break
```

Comment: Are u in sandbox mode ?

Comment: you still need user-id, it can be id or `self`

Comment: @krisrak, thanks for the reply but same result with the user-id

Comment: does the API url with access_token work in browser ?